# AJAX Edit Node and update

Tags: ajax

Im reading up on how to add AJAX functionality to nodes and am stuck. Where exactly do I place  #ajax in order to make the edit field updae via ajax? Specifically is it an existing php, js, html, css file that handles this? Do I add it to the node or block?  I've read that its fairly simple but drupal isn't my native language so i'm still learning.

I've tried using this module [ajax_form_entitty](https://drupal.org/project/ajax_form_entity)

but it wont load the newly created node after submission it directs to a blank page. I've been told to point the node to a div and insert the div in the header, but I have no idea how that should look.
here is what i've done (which doesn't work)
[image: My settings]

All help is appreciated

EDIT:

[Reading Material](https://drupal.org/node/752056)
I've tried following along with this as one possible way to go about it but have no clue how to implement anything.

Comment: General remarks: Try to include at least some of the references that you have used so far and also relevant code snippets that you came up with until now. That way it's easier for anyone here to help you.

Comment: As stated i'm not even sure where to begin. I'm not even sure what code snippets I would use at all. Everything I read does not say what specifically to edit, it's all implied and i'm still learning by trial and error.

Comment: But you say that your are "reading up"? Just give some links, so people here have something to start with. Ajax form entity is a pretty young module, so it's totally possible that you have discovered a bug in the module. The module maintainer will probably be glad if you report this as an issue in the official [issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/ajax_form_entity).

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question of "where" do you add the AJAX functionality in a node form, the answer is in a form_alter. That can be done in a custom module or the theme's template.php file. I recommend a module so the functionality remains even if you change your theme.

A great resource is the [examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples) which is a group of example modules with great comments that assist developers in implementing Drupal functionality. In fact, there's is a submodule called ajax_example that adds ajax functionality to a a field in a node (exactly what you are looking for!). Here's an excerpt from ajax_examples_node_form_alter.inc:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for the node form.
 *
 * Adds two fields to the node form, second only appears after first is enabled.
 */
function ajax_example_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $node = $form['#node'];
  $form['ajax_example_1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('AJAX Example 1'),
    '#description' => t('Enable to show second field.'),
    '#default_value' => $node->ajax_example['example_1'],
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_example_form_node_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'ajax-example-form-node',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    )
  );
  $form['container'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="ajax-example-form-node">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  // If the state values exist and 'ajax_example_1' state value is 1 or
  // if the state values don't exist and 'example1' variable is 1 then
  // display the ajax_example_2 field.
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['ajax_example_1']) && $form_state['values']['ajax_example_1'] == 1
      || empty($form_state['values']) && $node->ajax_example['example_1']) {

    $form['container']['ajax_example_2'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('AJAX Example 2'),
      '#description' => t('AJAX Example 2'),
      '#default_value' => empty($form_state['values']['ajax_example_2']) ?
                          $node->ajax_example['example_2'] :
                          $form_state['values']['ajax_example_2'],
    );
  }
}

/**
 * Returns changed part of the form.
 *
 * @return renderable array
 *
 * @see ajax_example_form_node_form_alter()
 */
function ajax_example_form_node_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['container'];
}
```

Comment: I think we're getting there! I've played with the module some and my last question is, if I implement that in a new module or in my templates php file, could I have it submit the content and edit the content via ajax so that I don't reload the page?

Comment: I'm going to cheat here and just point you to the edit module. :) https://drupal.org/project/edit

Comment: Unfortunately the EDIT module does not work with views and mediafront.